# Google-Chrome: Save as Complete Web Page

Tags: google-chrome

Once I have saved the complete web with, can I open it to view and subsequently print?

Answer (score 2):

This will save the HTML for the webpage as well as other resources needed to display it. You can open the HTML file in Chrome or another web browser later and print it.

Comment: it still does not get all other resources in v17 . i use scrapbook addon from firefox